# compare multiple columns of 2 tables which some columns having comma separated values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having 2 tables as below

## TABLE A:

[image]

## TABLE B:

[image]

I want to compare the columns of both tables and expected below output.

conditions:

1)All column values should match (atleast one value in comma separated values of a column)

Example :

if we take cbn100(cf1,cf2,cf3 column values) from 2nd table compare with first table M1001 (cf1,cf2,cf3 column values)

1. M1001.cf1 (co1)     = cbn100.cf1 (co1) - true
2. M1001.cf2 (co2,co3) = cbn100.cf2 (co2) - true (atleast 1 (co2) value matching)
3. M1001.cf3 (co4)     = cbn100.cf3 (co4) - true

Hence all values matching, the output should be M1001=cbn100

2)If the Null value is compared with non null value ,condition is true

Example:

If we take cbn103 valUes from 2nd table and compare with m1002 in first table

1. M1002 (null) = cbn103.cf1(co1) - true
2. M1002 (null) = cbn103.cf1(co5) - true
3. M1002 (co7)  =  cbn103.cf3(co7,co4) - true

Hence all condition matches the output should be M1002=cbn103

## Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (may need tweaking, only tested with your data set):

```
select result_
from (
  select 
    case when
      ( AB1 = 'true' and AB2 = 'true' and AB3 = 'true' )  
      or
      ( BA1 = 'true' and BA2 = 'true' and BA3 = 'true' )  
      then mfpartno || '=' || cbn
    end result_
  from (
    select
      A.mfpartno
    , B.cbn
    , case when instr( A.cf1, B.cf1 ) > 0 or B.cf1 is null then 'true' else 'false' end AB1
    , case when instr( A.cf2, B.cf2 ) > 0 or B.cf2 is null then 'true' else 'false' end AB2
    , case when instr( A.cf3, B.cf3 ) > 0 or B.cf3 is null then 'true' else 'false' end AB3
    , case when instr( B.cf1, A.cf1 ) > 0 or A.cf1 is null then 'true' else 'false' end BA1
    , case when instr( B.cf2, A.cf2 ) > 0 or A.cf2 is null then 'true' else 'false' end BA2
    , case when instr( B.cf3, A.cf3 ) > 0 or A.cf3 is null then 'true' else 'false' end BA3
    from tablea A cross join tableb B
  )
)
where result_ is not null
;
```

Result

```
        RESULT_ 
_______________ 
M1001=cbn100    
M1002=cbn103
```

Explanation

The inner query uses a CROSS JOIN, which allows us to compare all possible combinations of rows.  INSTR() is used for detecting whether a string of tableA contains a string from tableB (and vice versa).  There is also a condition for treating NULLs as per your requirements.  If we get 3 'true' results, then a "match" has been found.
DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82ba46c6a79c3f3e514acfd9fb43dcba).